# Inserting k keys into binary heap

Tags: algorithms

I came across this theoretical problem:

> Suggest an algorithm which inserts, into binary heap with $n$ elements, $k$ given keys in worst case time $O(k+\log^2 n)$.

And I'm wondering how is it possible? I know that we can build binary heap in linear time, so I was trying maybe to construct binary heap from given keys (given in advance - maybe it is very relevant?) and then somehow smartly merge these heaps. But I don't know how to do that. Can anybody help?

Comment: Sounds like a case where the trick is to _choose_ between either heapifying everything from scratch or inserting the new elements one at a time, based in the sizes of $n$ and $k$. If $n$ is small you want the former; if $k$ is small you want the latter.